# Restrict access to certain dashboard pages based on user id

Tags: users, dashboard

I have a client who want's to be given admin access to the dashboard of the test installation of her website on my server.

She hasn't paid me yet so I don't want her to be able to go into the themes menu, copy the theme code and run off without paying.

So, is there a way that I can give her admin access while also blocking her from viewing the Appearance > Editor menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just [disable the editor entirely](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Disable_the_Plugin_and_Theme_Editor). It is a dangerous tool anyway. I compare it to working on an airplane while its flying. Edit `wp-config.php` to add:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',true);
```

You can reverse that by re-editing your `wp-config.php` and uploading over FTP (or maybe you have direct file access), as you should be doing anyway, but no one will be able to get to the editor to mess around with things.